# Set end of day instead of 00:00:00 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

When we pass a date value like this `2019-01-01` without the time `10:00:00`, the time defaults to `00:00:00`. So finally the db compatible value gets transformed into this: `2019-01-01 00:00:00`. How can I force default it to `23:59:00` instead?

Example: I need to set an `expiry_date` attribute, but if I only take the date input `2019-01-08` from user, the user is going to assume that they will have the entire day as expiry date, when in reality it will expire at the very first second of `2019-01-08` because of the implicit default time `00:00:00`.

How do I overcome this? How can I set a mutator for `expiry_date` that would turn this `2019-01-01 00:00:00` into this `2019-01-01 23:59:00`?

Comment: It might be simpler to just compare the date portions e.g. something like `DATE(expiry_date) > CURDATE()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
$expiryDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->endOfDay()->toDateTimeString();
```

This will take the date (update date format if needed), switch to the end of the day and convert the resulting object into a date time string.

Or, use it as an attribute setter:

```
/**
 * @param $value
 */
public function setExpiryDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['expiry_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)
        ->endOfDay()
        ->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like the strtotime() function to add something to the current timestamp. `$expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours'))`.

If you need variables in the function, you must use double quotes then like strtotime("+{$hours} hours"), however better you use `strtotime(sprintf("+%d hours", $hours))` then.

Answer (score 1):

I used an DateTime property method like below:

```
date_create($your_date)->modify('+1 day -1 microsecond'),
```

It works on Laravel because datetime is PHP native.

[-> Source <-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70493096/10335866)

Answer (score 0):

just hard code the time of day:

$expiry_date = $your_date->format("Y-m-d 23:59:00");